# query execution time in query result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can i get query actual execution time (of all query) in query result PostgreSQL?
Like this:

```
select __get_execution_time() some_column
```

return:

```
 some_column
 -----------
 1 sec
```

Is it possible to imlement such a function? I want to get result and execution time in one query.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function in PostgreSQL.

What you can do is run

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT 'json') SELECT ...
```

and get the `"Planning Time"` and `"Execution Time"` properties from the result.

Comment: Is it possible to imlement such a function? I want to get result and execution time in one query.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. How to give all of query into function args? Can you help me?